# Find if Given number is power of 2 or not

Tags: java, string, algorithm, types, overflow

Find if the Given number is a power of 2 or not.

**Input:** Number length can be more than 64, which means the number can be greater than 2 ^ 64 (out of long long range) (Given as a string)

**Output:** Return 1 if the number is a power of 2 else return 0

**Example:**
Input: 128
Output: 1

This is on a coding platform, and BigInteger was not imported(i.e. Math class was not imported). I had to perform operations on the string either without modifying its datatype or using a mathematical formula to prevent overflow.

```
class Solution {
  public static int power(String A) {
      /* write your solution here */
      while(Integer.parseInt(A)>1){
          if(Integer.parseInt(A)%2!=0)
          return 0;
       A=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(A)/2);
      }
      return 1;
      
      //long num=Long.parseUnsignedLong(A);
      //while(num>1){
      //    if(num%2!=0)
           //  return 0;
         //num=num/2;
       //}
      // return 1; // The input can be up to 21 characters long, and that's why unsigned long didn't work.
      
  }
}
```

What am I supposed to do? (In java only, please)

Comment: *"... and `BigInteger` was not imported"*.  Are you sure?  `BigInteger` is a Java SE and Java Android class.  You should be able to import it in your Java code.

Comment: What is the max length possible for the string?

Comment: *Number length possibly > 64, implying number possibly > 2^64* Is the number specified in decimal representation, *base 2* or otherwise?

Comment: Start with simple cases: empty string, first character not in "+-012468". Find out some things about *base conversion* and *modulo arithmetic*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a huge integer number as a string, check if its a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677174/given-a-huge-integer-number-as-a-string-check-if-its-a-power-of-2)

Comment: @Stephen C this question was on a programming platform, so the Math class was not imported.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest working in the opposite direction, and create a string that starts as "1" and then "double" it while it represents a number that is less than the number represented by the target string. Return 1 when it is equal, 0 otherwise:

```
    public static int power(String s) {
        String p = "1";
        int psize = 1;
        s = s.replaceAll("^0+", ""); // Only needed if input is not normalized
        int size = s.length();
        while (psize < size || psize == size && p.compareTo(s) < 0) {
            // multiply p by 2;
            int carry = 0;
            StringBuffer sum = new StringBuffer(psize + 1);
            sum.setLength(psize + 1);
            for (int i = psize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                int digit = (p.charAt(i) - '0') * 2 + carry;
                sum.setCharAt(i + 1, (char) (digit % 10 + '0'));
                carry = digit / 10;
            }
            sum.setCharAt(0, (char) (carry + '0'));
            p = sum.substring(1 - carry);
            psize += carry;
        }
        return p.equals(s) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

To reduce memory consumption you could also do this with just one string buffer:

```
    public static int power(String s) {
        s = s.replaceAll("^0+", ""); // Only needed if input is not normalized
        int size = s.length();
        if (size == 0) return 0;
        
        StringBuffer sum = new StringBuffer(size);
        sum.setLength(size);
        // The current power of 2 is encoded in the string buffer 
        //    in a right-aligned manner:
        int start = size - 1;
        sum.setCharAt(start, '1'); 
        
        while (start > 0 || sum.charAt(0) < s.charAt(0)) {
            // Multiply number encoded in stringbuffer by 2;
            int carry = 0;
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= start; i--) {
                int digit = (sum.charAt(i) - '0') * 2 + carry;
                sum.setCharAt(i, (char) (digit % 10 + '0'));
                carry = digit / 10;
            }
            if (carry > 0) {
                start--;
                if (start < 0) return 0;
                sum.setCharAt(start, '1');
            }
        }
        return sum.toString().equals(s) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

In a code comment you had written that the input will have no more than 21 characters. There are 67 powers of 2 that fit that condition, so you could even consider storing those powers (as strings) in an array, optionally grouped by the number of characters they have, and look for a match...

Comment: I liked your idea. I tried it out, and only 2/5 of the hidden test cases passed.

Comment: For storing the powers of 2 in an array, I need to use BigInteger, which is not imported.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. You need to import BigInteger, or you should not use it?

Comment: BTW, I had tested this code thoroughly. If you cannot tell me for which input it is wrong, then I will just move on. However, it would be useful if you would quote the code challenge **literally**, so that we could spot some requirement that we may have missed.

Comment: All the required packages were already imported, and Math class was not one of them. So I can't use BigInteger

Comment: I pasted the problem verbatim. And added some of the things I got to know after testing code, like input is up to 21 digits long.

Comment: My answer doesn't suggest to use BigInteger, so I don't know what you are getting at. If that is all that the code challenge says, then I stick with this answer. Sorry if it doesn't work for you. Your question has been closed. I should add that "number" is ambiguous. For instance, where does it say the number is an **integer**, that it is represented in **decimal base**, that it is **unsigned**? All these aspects are important. I would look for a different code challenge site -- where the constraints are clearly and unambiguously listed.

Comment: How to store such large numbers in an array? I'd have to use BigInteger, right?

Comment: No, just precalculate them (on a piece of paper if you want, or with Python, or... whatever), and put them as hard coded as strings in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert a decimal number to binary, all the number that are power of 2 has a starting 1 with rest are 0.

```
1:10
2:100
3:1000
4:10000
5:100000
6:1000000
```

So first, you need to convert the string number to binary string and then check if this pattern matches(maybe with a loop). You can easily find the first part online if you struggle.

Comment: _you need to convert the string number to binary string_ that is where the actual task is.

Answer (score -1):

This half() method divides String by 2 and returns the String.
Keep dividing until result is short enough to convert to int.
Test if the int is power of 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "562949953421312";
    while (x.length() > 4)
        x = half(x);
    System.out.println(isPowerOf2(Integer.parseInt(x)));
}

public static String half(String x)
{
    AtomicInteger over = new AtomicInteger(0);
    String half = Arrays.stream(x.split(""))
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .map(a -> {
                int next = (over.get()+a)/2;
                over.set( a % 2 == 0? 0 : 10);
                return next;
            })
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    half = half.replaceAll("^0", ""); //removing leading 0
    return half;
}
public static boolean isPowerOf2(int number)
{
    // 2^x is always binary 1 followed by zeros
    int bitwiseAnd = (number - 1) & number;
    return bitwiseAnd == 0;
}
```

Comment: The atomic package is not imported in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int isPowerOfTwo(String number) {
    // Remove leading zeros
    number = number.replaceAll("^0+", "");
    
    // If the number is zero or has more than one non-zero digit, it's not a power of two
    if (number.length() == 0 || (number.length() > 1 && !number.equals("1"))) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Convert the last digit to an integer
    int lastDigit = number.charAt(number.length() - 1) - '0';
    
    // If the last digit is odd, it's not a power of two
    if (lastDigit % 2 == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Divide the number by two until it becomes 1 or an odd number
    while (number.length() > 1) {
        int carry = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            int digit = number.charAt(i) - '0';
            int temp = carry * 10 + digit;
            sb.append(temp / 2);
            carry = temp % 2;
        }
        number = sb.toString().replaceAll("^0+", "");
        if (carry == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

Working of the code :

1. We remove any leading zeros from the input string since they don't affect whether the number is a power of two or not.
2. If the number is zero or has more than one non-zero digit, it can't be a power of two, so we return 0.
3. Otherwise, we check if the last digit is odd. If it is, the number can't be a power of two, so we return 0.
4. If the last digit is even, we divide the number by two until it becomes 1 or an odd number. We do this by repeatedly dividing each digit of the number by 2, keeping track of any carry, and appending the result to a StringBuilder. If there's a carry left over after the division, the number isn't a power of two and we return 0.
5. If we reach the end of the loop and the number is 1, it's a power of two, so we return 1.

**Note:** This code assumes that the input string represents a non-negative integer. If negative numbers are allowed, you may need to add additional checks to handle them properly.

Comment: No string of length > 1 equals `"1"`. Test for "+4".